# Javascript Is there a way to detect a page has been requested

Tags: javascript

At the very moment an a-tag has been clicked and the browser commences to request the URL. Is there a way to detect that request and what the URL request is?

Comment: Do you want to detect the request in you browser?

Comment: For debugging? In an extension? As a _regular_ script on the page?

Comment: I was considering onbeforeunload but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At the very moment an a-tag has been clicked and the browser commences
>   to request the URL

If you are sure that only way a page (URL) will be requested is by clicking a link, then you can add an event listener to the anchor tags of the page

In pure JS

```
var allAnchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for ( var counter = 0; counter < allAnchors.length; counter++)
{
    allAnchors[counter].addEventListener( "click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var src = this.getAttribute( "href" );
      alert( "This link was clicked " + src )
      location.href = src;
    }, false );
}
```

In jQuery

```
$( "a" ).click( function(){
      e.preventDefault();
      alert( "This link was clicked " + $( this ).attr( "href" ) );
      location.href = $( this ).attr( "href" );
} );
```

Comment: I have this configuration. But I am having a situation where the href in the a-tag is not firing.

Comment: OH! I like "e.preventDefault();"  Not at all the answer I was expecting... but it did solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

For the requested URL , you can use the code below :-

```
    document.referrer;
```

Comment: "document.referrer" gave me the last request, not the current request.